# Does the Wii U game pad actually detect breath?

Tags: controllers, wii-u

In both *Wii Fit U* and *NintendoLand* there are games where you have to blow into the game pad's microphone to complete them. I don't like the idea of blowing moisture into electronics so I've tried to cheat by making sounds like I'm blowing in the microphone but it cleverly detects that I'm not doing it properly. Can it actually detect breath or would the right sound fool it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The game pad cannot detect your breath, rather it listens for a sound similar to that of you blowing. So yes, the right sound would fool it.

I also know that Mariocart on the DS uses the microphone in this way.

Comment: I didn't think it would do anything other than detect specific sounds but how do you _know_ this is the case?

Comment: There was an "environmental" mystery game on the DS really early on that used the microphone for that, without ever telling me so.  I was stuck on a puzzle for hours before I sighed into the microphone I didn't even know the DS had and it revealed where someone had written on glass with their finger.

Comment: @CJDennis, I have tried and it is possible to make a sound away from the DS which triggers the actions.

Comment: @CJDennis Also a sensor for this kind of input would be too expensive/large to be a practical sensor on the Gamepad/DS

Comment: @CJDEnnis If you got a microphone on your pc, record yourself blowing in it, you'll hear something. That's exactly what the games are "listening" for too. Since no one blows exactly the same way, the sound differs so the games need to listen to a specific range of that sound that is the most commonly found when people blow in a microphone.

Comment: I've been able to fool the game by making a very loud "F" sound close to the microphone. As in, this activity is "F....."!

Comment: @angussidney, not necessarily. you can get breathalyzer keychains for a few bucks, so a sensor on a controller ought to raise the price by only a couple bucks.